# How to append element after first child div in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Assuming I have the following divs:

```
<div id="mydiv">
 <div>1</div>
 <div>2</div>
 <div>3</div>
 <div>4</div>
</div>
```

How can I in jquery or javascript make it such that I can append an element right after the first child of "mydiv". Or is there some selector to allow me to select and append after the first child?

```
<div>
 <div>1</div>
 <div>Place to Insert Subsequent div</div>
 <div>2</div>
 <div>3</div>
 <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do this using [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) and [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

```
$("#mydiv div:first-child").after(newDiv);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TRu23/)

Answer (score 18):

I prefer using [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead of `first-child` because it's more flexible, in case I ever wanted to change it to be after the 2nd or 3rd div, i can just change the `0` value in the `eq(0)` function to `eq(1)` or `eq(2)`.

```
 $("#mydiv div:eq(0)").after('<div>Place to Insert Subsequent div</div>')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KjY7H/

Answer (score 1):

To maintain readability you can store in a variable the div you want to append:

```
var subsequentDiv = $('<div>Place to Insert Subsequent div</div>');
```

Then using your variable use your prefered jQuery method, in my example I'm using "insertAfter":

```
subsequentDiv.insertAfter('#mydiv div:eq(0)'); // selects children by its index, the first div is equal to 0  
subsequentDiv.insertAfter('#mydiv div:lt(1)'); // selects children that its index is lower than 1 (it means the second div)
```

A different way to achieve the same result, is by reading the content of the div with the "contains filter":

```
subsequentDiv.insertAfter('#mydiv div:contains("1")');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cadence96/tyBnX/1/