# How to insert contents from AJAX result into an element without removing its existing contents?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'd like to first point out that english is not my first language and im a newbie tryna learn news things so i apologize if i might sound confusing.

So here it goes, im trying to make an image viewer for my local image files and i decided to try and make a "load more" button using jquery/ajax & php so it doesn't show all the files on the selected directory.

Here's my **process.php**:

```
function response($status,$imgs,$count,$last) {
    $status = array(
        'status'    => $status,
        'imgs'      => $imgs,
        'count' => $count,
        'last' => $last
    );
    return json_encode($status);
}  


$files = glob("assets/images/shop/*.*");
$total_records = count($files);

$viewmore = (int)$_POST['viewmore'];

$per_page = 10;

$perpage = array_slice($files, $viewmore, $per_page, true);


$i = 0;
$thumbs = array();
foreach ($perpage as $key => $value) {

    
   $image = $perpage[$key];
    $supported_file = array(
            'gif',
            'jpg',
            'png'
     );

    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));    
    
    if($ext == 'gif'){
        $fext = 2;
    }elseif($ext == 'png'){
        $fext = 1;
    }elseif($ext == 'jpg'){
        $fext = 0;
    } 
    
    $imgfilename = pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    
    if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
        $id = ($i+1);
        $thumbs[] = '<img src="'.$image .'" data-name="'.$imgfilename.'" data-ext="'.$fext.'" style="width:50px;margin:5px" />';
    } else {
        continue;
    }   
$i++;

}

$num = $viewmore + $per_page;
$last = $key + 1;

echo response(0,$thumbs,$num,$last);
```

My **jQuery/Ajax**:

```
    $(document).on("submit",".imgViewMore",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".imgViewMore").attr("disabled", true);
    $(".imgViewMore").val("Loading..");
    
    var data = $(".imgViewMore").serialize();
    var process = 0;
    if (process == 0){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/process.php",
            data: data,     
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                if(data.last >= <?php echo $total_records;?>){
                    $(".imgViewMore").hide();
                }else{
                    $("#imgViewerContainer").append(data.imgs); // NEED HELP HERE
                    $("#viewmore").val(data.count);
                    $(".imgViewMore").attr("disabled", false);
                }
                $(".imgViewMore").val("Load More");
            },
            error: function(){
                //alert('Oops! There seem to be an issue..');
            },
        });
    }
});
```

I manage to get the data i needed for each ajax load/loop using those codes however, i really can't figure out how to ouput all those formatted data/images on the array that was created from process.php into the **#imgViewerContainer** element.

**The ajax load/result looks like this:**

```
<img src="filename.extension">
<img src="filename.extension">
<img src="filename.extension">
<img src="filename.extension">
<img src="filename.extension">
```

Basically, **on page load** the target element have contents and looks like this:

```
<div id="imgViewerContainer">
   <img src="filename.extension">
   <img src="filename.extension">
   <img src="filename.extension">
   <img src="filename.extension">
   <img src="filename.extension">
   <form method="post" class="imgViewMore"><input type="hidden" ><input type="submit" class="imgViewMore"></form>
<!--NEED TO INSERT data.imgs HERE FROM THE AJAX RESULT  -->
</div>
```

So i need to insert each ajax results inside & at the bottom of **#imgViewerContainer**  element. I decided to try and use **append()** & **html()** and **got this error**:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node':
> parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Any help, guide or explantion is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I am not very experienced in JQuery but I can recommend two solutions: (1) you can create a container after the form element (e.g. <div id="list"></div>) and place the img elements inside that element, or (2) check the answers in the following link to see how to append after a child: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354892/how-to-append-element-after-first-child-div-in-jquery

Comment: From that error it would seem your `data.imgs` is not what you think it is, if you do `console.log(data.imgs)` is it being displayed as an array of strings?

Comment: Thank you for your replies! they're both helpful as well and might help me in the future to, especially the console log. I really learn a lot from here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you get error in append because the data.imgs is array

in process.php change this:

```
$thumbs = array();
$thumbs[] =
```

to this:

```
$thumbs = '';
$thumbs .=
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you very much! Just a quick question tho, im a newbie, what does `.=` do?

Comment: So i learned from w3schools that .= appends every new value on the variable instead of making an array. I learn more everyday, thank you very much!

Comment: you can also resolve problem from jquery script
        by change this:
        `$("#imgViewerContainer").append(data.imgs);`

        to this:
        `var imgs = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < data.imgs.length; i++) {
            imgs += data.imgs[i];
        }
        $("#imgViewerContainer").append(imgs);`

Comment: **.=** appends every new value on the variable in php  and **+=** in javascript